# Joint_state_publisher syntax error in urdf_tutorial

Tags: joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the urdf tutorial found at /wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch *(sorrie can't post links)*

But whenever I try to start the display of the first model using:

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf
```

Rviz crashes. In order to find my problem I tried to start everything manually, but when I run `rosrun joint_state_publisher joint_state_publisher _robot_description:=01-myfirst.urdf`. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_visualization/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 202, in <module>
    jsp = JointStatePublisher()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/robot_model_visualization/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 25, in __init__
    robot = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(description).getElementsByTagName('robot')[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1931, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

I haven't been able to find this syntax error, as I am directly using the xml file from the tutorial page.

I am using Groovy on Ubuntu 13.04.

Does someone know how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67767/joint_state_publisher-syntax-error-in-urdf_tutorial/) by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5418/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-20**:
I have the same problem. I am using ROS groovy and Ubuntu 12.04;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the problem (and the solution).

joint_state_publisher requires not the name of the file, but the actual text. So it was trying to parse the text 01-myfirst.urdf as xml file.

So I now set the robot_description parameter using

```
rosparam set robot_description --textfile=01-myfirst.urdf
```

And now it workts.

---

Originally posted by [LordTimmeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5460/lordtimmeh/) with karma: 18 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0